# How to one-line this search?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a very long line, where I would like to find all the links when they are followed by `class="filelink"`

A link could look like this

```
<a href="https://example.com/@api/files/123/=2008.pdf" class="filelink"
```

How is such a problem written as a Perl one-liner?

**Update**

If I do

```
echo '<a href="https://example.com/@api/files/123/=2008.pdf" class="filelink"' > test
perl -pe 's/href="(.*)" class="filelink"/\1/g' test
```

then I get

```
<a https://example.com/@api/files/123/=2008.pdf
```

where I would have expected

```
https://example.com/@api/files/123/=2008.pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -nE'say for m/<a\s+href="([^"]+)"\s+class="filelink"[^>]*>/g;'
```

Comment: When I append ` test` to you command I don't see any output. `test` is the file I described in the post. Do I use it wrong?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting You need to put `>` on the end of your `echo` line.

Comment: What is the difference of `perl -pnE` and your `say for` trick?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting I used `-n` instead of `-p` so that it wouldn't print the entire line. I used `-E` instead of `-e` so that I could use `say` otherwise it would be `print "$_\n" for ...`

Answer (score 10):

Solution with robust HTML parser instead of regex:

```
<input_long_line.html perl -MWeb::Query=wq -ne '
    wq($_)
    ->find("a.filelink")
    ->each(sub {
        printf "URL %s\t text %s\n", $_[1]->attr("href"), $_[1]->text
    })'
```

I wrapped it for readability, it runs fine as a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach using `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`, which I find to be quite nice:

```
M=HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath; \
perl -M$M -le 'print $_->attr("href") for ' \
           -e "$M->new_from_content(<STDIN>)->" \
           -e 'findnodes(q(//a[@class="filelink"]))' < input-file
```